# Decomposition and decoding of nested dictionary/json

Tags: python, json, encoding, dictionary, decomposition

In my app I'm connecting to a server which returns some json style unicode string resembling dictionary of dictionaries. As a result I'd like to get one leveled dictionary with `id` as a key and unicode value like this :

`{'1': u'autos','3': u'cities'}`

So I load the response with built in json module :

```
>>> jsonData = json.loads(data)
>>> jsonData
{u'1': {u'id': u'1', u'name': u'autos'}, u'3': {u'id': u'3', u'name': u'cities'}, u'2': {u'id': u'2', u'name': u'business'},}
>>> type(jsonData)
<type 'dict'>
```

You can see the returned object here. Then I should decompose it to get rid of the parent dictionary. And finally encode the id's. I've found two methods how to do the encoding. One :

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', data).encode('ascii','ignore')
```

and second:

```
>>> data.encode('ascii','ignore')
```

How I should do this task, especially the decomposition ?

Comment: How do you mean "get rid of the parent dictionary"? Can you specify what you want it to look like when you've finished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
outputdata = {}
for id, stuff in jsonData.iteritems():
    outputdata[id.encode("ascii")] = stuff[u"name"]
```

You could also use a generator expression, as in dugres' answer.

Comment: `dict((i.encode("ascii"),s[u"name"]) for i,s in jsonData.items())` would be even shorter (but essentially the same).

Comment: @Sven: And if you're using 2.7/3.1, it's even shorter: `{i.encode("ascii"): s[u"name"] for i, s in jsonData.items()}`. But I thought I'd stick to basics ;-)

Comment: Oh, and I just notice that we did not use `iteritems()` in the 2.x case, but should have...

Answer (score 0):

```
decomp=dict((v['id'], v['name']) for v in jsondata.values())
```

Comment: cannot use generator since id is not relevant to the actual position. Still thanks for answer.